# Were "Mrs." and "Mustard/Parking ticket song" from Buffy ever released?

Tags: soundtrack, joss-whedon

The *Buffy* episode [*Once More, with Feeling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_More,_with_Feeling_%28Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer%29) is performed as as musical, where the actors sing several songs. All of these songs were released on a [soundtrack of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_More,_with_Feeling_%28Buffy_soundtrack%29).

In a later episode ([*Selfless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfless_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer))), we see a flashback to the musical episode, where two new songs are performed:

- **Mrs.** (sung by Emma Caulfield, written by Joss Whedon, produced and arranged by Douglas Romayne, orchestrated by Wataru Hokoyama)
- **Mustard/Parking ticket song** (sung by Marti Noxon and David Fury, written by Joss Whedon)

These songs are not included in the soundtrack to *Once More, with Feeling*, and unless I missed something, the Wikipedia article about [Music in *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* and *Angel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_in_Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer_and_Angel) doesn’t mention another release where these two songs are included.

Was there any release that included these songs? Maybe as bonus material to a series DVD or so?

Comment: This question is more food for the [related Meta discussion](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/70/47).

Comment: This question does not quite fall under the same definition as that Meta discussion. I've created [a new discussion](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/116/are-was-this-ever-released-questions-on-topic) to deal with these questions.

Comment: According to [a Youtube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O06DGow63c&google_comment_id=z12fvrlimzvmt1nga04cixkihseqgrjjeug0k), the first song isn't a lost *Once More, With Feeling* bit, but rather something written specifically for *Selfless*. This is apparently mentioned in the DVD commentary, but I can't check since the DVDs are at home. :)